# ListViewItemCollection.Insert broken?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, controls

I am trying to allow users to drag image files into a ListView control and display the image wherever the user inserts the file. However, for some reason, it seems that `ListViewItemCollection.Insert` does not insert the item at the specified index, but rather, it adds it to the end of the list. I am using a custom control that inherits from ListView that raises an event when a file is dropped onto it:

```
//In my ListView control
var objPaths = (string[])(drgevent.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
if (objPaths != null && objPaths.Length > 0)
{
     var e = new DragDropFileEventArgs(objPaths, targetIndex);
     OnDropFile(e);
}
```

And I am using this in my form:

```
//Handle drag 'n dropped files
void imageListView_DropFile(object sender, DragDropFileEventArgs e)
{
    //Loads the files from e.Paths and returns the images added
    var addedImages = myListOfImages.LoadFromFiles(e.Paths, e.Index);

    for (int i = 0; i < addedImages.Length; i++)
    {
        var img = addedImages[i];
        ListViewItem.LargeImageList.Images.Add(img.Image);
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem((e.Index + i).ToString(), _imageList.Images.Count - 1);
        imageListView.Items.Insert(e.Index + i, item);
    }
}
```

For some reason though, the items are being added to the end of `imageListView.Items`.

I can reproduce this with a new project with just the following code:

```
        listView1.Items.Add("a");
        listView1.Items.Add("b");
        listView1.Items.Add("c");
        listView1.Items.Add("d");
        listView1.Items.Insert(1, "added");
```

The added item still goes to the end of the ListView.

Any ideas? Am I missing a ListView setting, or is this a bug?

Edit: I must use View.LargeIcon, because the point of this was to display images in the ListView. I know that I can just remove all items from the ListView and re-add them one by one, but I was looking for a method that doesn't cause flashing and doesn't lose my scroll position in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an item into a specific position in a Listview will possible only in View.List mode. The below code works fine. Please try whether it fit for you or not. Also please mark the answer if useful.

```
ListView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List
ListView1.Items.Add("a")
ListView1.Items.Add("b")
ListView1.Items.Add("c")
ListView1.Items.Add("d")
ListView1.Items.Insert(1, "added")
```

Comment: Ah, that does indeed fix the problem, but I need to display the images in the ListView, so I must use View = View.LargeIcon. Are there any other ways? Setting it to View.List, then inserting the item, then setting it back to View.LargeIcon works, but I lose my scroll position, which was the whole issue I was trying to avoid (that is, clearing the list and repopulating it from scratch).